# How do I copy or alias an object in C++11 using rvalues?

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

I want to know if my understanding of the problem is correct, and if so, how it might be solved.

I'm programming a template class to store a number of type objects and perform operations on them.  The problem is that my skills are still inferior so even after reading [11 pages about rvalues](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html) I don't totally get it.  In my template class, if I understand correctly, an overloaded rvalue copy function would make it so that the code in the main function would result in an error when the line 'cout << ex.z;' is executed because instead of 'test = move(ex);' calling the lvalue copy function it would call the rvalue one which would result in 'ex' referencing what test referenced and 'test' referencing what 'ex' referenced?

If that is correct, how do I properly implement the rvalue object copy function?  My primary interest in being able to do this is to create a constructor that takes an rvalue properly instead of essentially just working like my lvalue constructor does and the roundabout method is to make sure I understand it.

```
template<class T>
class Vec3
{
public:
    Vec3(){}
    Vec3(const Vec3 &vec):x(vec.x),y(vec.y),z(vec.z){}

    void operator = (const Vec3 &other)
    {x=other.x; y=other.y; z=other.z;}

//    void operator = (Vec3 &&other)
//    {
//this would just call the other overloaded copy function
//        *this = move(other);
//    }

    T x, y, z;
};

main(){
  Vec3<int> ex(0,0,0);
  Vec3<int> test = move(ex);
  test.z++;
  cout << test.z;//will be 1
  cout << ex.z;//will be 0
}
```

Comment: Vec3<int> test = move(ex); does not fire operator=, it fires copy constructor. You should have rvalue copy constructor instead of operator=.

Comment: What would the copy constructor look like? 'Vec3(Vec3 &&vec){/*something akin to this=vec?*/}'

Comment: Unless there is something special about `x`, `y` and `z` you are probably better off letting the compiler generate your copy and move functions for you. (unless you are using Visual Studio 2013 which doesn't generate move functions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it should look like:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Vec3
{
public:
    Vec3() {}
    Vec3(T x_, T y_, T z_): x(x_), y(y_), z(z_)
    {}
    Vec3(const Vec3 &vec):x(vec.x),y(vec.y),z(vec.z)
    {}
    Vec3(Vec3 &&vec) noexcept : x(std::move(vec.x)),y(std::move(vec.y)),z(std::move(vec.z))
    {}
    Vec3& operator=(const Vec3 &other)
    {
        x=other.x; y=other.y; z=other.z;
        return *this;
    }
    Vec3& operator=(Vec3 &&other) noexcept
    {
        x = std::move(other.x);
        y = std::move(other.y);
        z = std::move(other.z);
        return *this;
    }

    T x, y, z;
};

int main(){
  Vec3<int> ex(0,0,0);
  Vec3<int> ex1(1,1,1);
  ex1 = std::move(ex); // <-- this will call move assignment operator
  Vec3<int> test = std::move(ex); // <-- this will call move constructor
  test.z++;
  std::cout << test.z;//will be 1
  std::cout << ex.z;//will be 0
  return 0;
}
```

I personally prefer using `swap` idiom:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
class Vec3
{
public:
    Vec3() {}
    Vec3(T x_, T y_, T z_): x(x_), y(y_), z(z_)
    {}
    Vec3(const Vec3 &vec):x(vec.x),y(vec.y),z(vec.z)
    {}
    Vec3(Vec3 &&other) noexcept
    { swap(other); }
    Vec3& operator=(const Vec3 &other)
    {
        x=other.x; y=other.y; z=other.z;
        return *this;
    }
    Vec3& operator=(Vec3 &&other) noexcept
    {
        Vec3{std::move(other)}.swap(*this);
        return *this;
    }
    void swap(Vec3 &other) noexcept
    {
        std::swap(x, other.x);
        std::swap(y, other.y);
        std::swap(z, other.z);
    }
    T x, y, z;
};

main(){
  Vec3<int> ex(0,0,0);
  Vec3<int> ex1(1,1,1);
  ex1 = std::move(ex); // <-- this will call move assignment operator
  Vec3<int> test = std::move(ex); // <-- this will call move constructor
  test.z++;
  std::cout << test.z;//will be 1
  std::cout << ex.z;//will be 0
}
```

Adding `noexcept` to your move constructor will benefit, when using your class in STL containers like `std::vector` etc. Container will use move instead of copy.

Comment: Thanks but, if after that code is executed I call 'test = Vec3<int>(0,0,3);' it will crash because the overloaded '=' operator implementing the rvalue does something odd.  Also, shouldn't it use forward since you're trying to have it use the constructor?  I was able to get it working by manually putting in 'x = move(other.x)' and so forth though.

Comment: Corrected the code. First version called move assignment operator recursively.

Comment: This is silly. For this class, all of the special member functions can and should be just explicitly defaulted. Writing them by hand is error prone and a pessimization, because they can no longer be trivial.  `swap` is also not a good way to implement move construction or move assignment, and this is especially bad in your code because 1) your move constructor is going to read uninitialized values, causing UB; and 2) your member `swap` is calling `swap` wrong.

Comment: This class was in the question. And question was - how to write move constructor for this class. So it is here. Of course for such simple class all this special methods are not needed to be explicitly defined, implicitly generated are enough. As for swap idiom it is just your opinion that it is not good, and you better write IMHO when making such statements.

Comment: You are  right that swap move constructor in this example can cause UB, my fault. I use swap when class members has initialization on declaration. What is wrong with swap method?

Comment: It's less efficient, and the whole point of move semantics is efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're misunderstanding something that's *not* related to rvalue-references.

In simple words, `Vec3<int> test = move(ex)` will call the move constructor for `Vec3<int>` with a single argument, an rvalue-reference to `ex`.

To understand this, you shall understand `std::move()`. What this template function does is to take either a lvalue-reference or a prvalue(Pure Rvalue, that is, what we have called "rvalues" since its origins a long, *long* time ago)-reference, and converts it into an *xvalue* (eXpring value, that is, one that data can be moved from). Such a value will bind to an rvalue-reference of its type.

After all this mess, the simple solution is to implement a move constructor:

```
Vec3(Vec3 &&vec) : x(std::move(vec.x)), y(std::move(vec.y)), z(std::move(vec.z)) {}
```

You can also apply this same principle to the assignment operator:

```
void operator=(Vec3 &&vec) {
    this->x = std::move(vec.x);
    this->y = std::move(vec.y);
    this->z = std::move(vec.z);
}
```

**Important**: Don't simply copy paste that last code snippet! C++11 introduces a *big* bunch of complex terminologies that are (usually) pretty difficult to grasp at first. If you didn't understood this post, read more explanations/examples until you do, otherwise your brain will invoke Undefined Behaviour as defined by the Neurological ABI Specification for the 8-bit *Homo Sapiens* (non-turing-complete) architecture as published by The Open Natural Selection Group in 75,000 BC.